# Particle interactions simulator

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, interactions, parity

I'm an A-Level student trying to write a program that will take in two particles (like a proton and electron) and output the new particles. I'm planning to implement the conservation laws so that the program can search for an outcome that obeys all the conditions. I've studied charge, energy, lepton and baryon number and strangeness. I'm studying about angular momentum and parity etc and was wondering if someone could simplify these concepts in relation to my problem and explain how the conservation laws could be used to predict the products of an interaction, or if anyone had a better way of calculating it. Thanks!

Comment: If you are only paying attention to conserved quantities, you aren't really simulating any particular *interactions*. For example, an electromagnetic interaction might be able to produce one set of particles, the weak interaction a second, and the strong interaction a third.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Conservation laws tell you what doesn't happen. Everything else happens.

Comment: @G.Smith How about a high energy electron-positron pair annihilating with a production of a quark-antiquark pair (and accordingly two hadron jets)? There are no strongly interacting particles at the input. Are you saying that the electromagnetic interaction of an electron and positron cannot produce strongly interacting particles? Otherwise, since it is unknown upfront what type of interaction will happen, what is the meaning of your comment?

Comment: @safesphere I agree that the electromagnetic interaction can produce a quark-antiquark pair and thus strongly-interacting particles. If the OP wants to simulate all interactions, then I agree with you that everything that isn’t forbidden by conservation laws can happen. If you want to simulate only, for example, EM interactions, then an electron-positron pair can produce a quark-antiquark pair, but that quark-antiquark pair can’t produce any gluons.

Comment: I think the OP is probably interested in considering all possible interactions, so my comment was not helpful.

Comment: " explain how the conservation laws could be used to predict the products of an interaction" You are trying to undertake what maybe thousands of theoretically trained physicists have been doing the past fifty years. After all it all ends up with a computer program calculating the probabilities of interacting , which is what your project is. Have a look for the analytic solutions for just an electron and a proton http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html . It becomes much more compicated when the energies involved go up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory

Comment: It is particle interaction simulators that the physicists use to draw the background  for new discoveries to be seen, as for example the Higgs . Maybe you should choose a less ambitious project.

Comment: Could I simpIify the problem by limiting the number of inputs or in other ways? It isnt my aim to create a program that would discover something new, so i thought i could abstract the process into something simpler than an actual particle collider. thanks for all the advice so far, its been very helpful :)

Comment: You should address your replies using the @ sign (no spaces). Otherwise people are not notified.

Comment: You need a list of all particles sorted by energy. Then loop through them iteratively based on the input energy and apply the conservation laws to each loop iteration to remove impossible outcomes. What is left will be a list of all possibilities.